# GORM Association error (got error unsupported data type: &[])

Tags: postgresql, go, associations, go-gorm

I am trying to do associations in go, one to many relationships. I have tried following the docs and ended  up with some weird error `got error unsupported data type: &[]`

```golang
// There are error for all models
// 1st Error
[error] failed to parse value &models.User{ID:uuid.UUID{0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, CreatedAt:time.Date(1, time.January, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC), UpdatedAt:time.Date(1, time.January, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC), Name:"", Email:"", Password:"", Role:"", Photo:"", ApiKey:"", Verified:false, Prompts:[]models.Prompt(nil), Folders:[]models.Folder(nil), Playgrounds:[]models.Playground(nil), PlaygroundID:uuid.UUID{0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}}, got error unsupported data type: &[]

// 2nd Error
[error] failed to parse value &models.Folder{ID:uuid.UUID{0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, CreatedAt:time.Date(1, time.January, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC), UpdatedAt:time.Date(1, time.January, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC), Name:"", AuthorID:uuid.UUID{0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, Prompts:[]models.Prompt(nil)}, got error unsupported data type: &[]

//3rd Error
[error] failed to parse value &models.Prompt{ID:uuid.UUID{0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, CreatedAt:time.Date(1, time.January, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC), UpdatedAt:time.Date(1, time.January, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC), Title:"", Prompt:"", Tags:[]string(nil), AuthorID:uuid.UUID{0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, FolderID:uuid.UUID{0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, Description:"", Playgrounds:[]models.Playground(nil)}, got error unsupported data type: &[]

// 4th Error
[error] failed to parse value &models.Playground{ID:uuid.UUID{0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, CreatedAt:time.Date(1, time.January, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC), UpdatedAt:time.Date(1, time.January, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC), Name:"", Template:"", Temprature:0x0, AiModel:"", TopPValue:0x0, Likes:0x0, Author:models.User{ID:uuid.UUID{0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, CreatedAt:time.Date(1, time.January, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC), UpdatedAt:time.Date(1, time.January, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC), Name:"", Email:"", Password:"", Role:"", Photo:"", ApiKey:"", Verified:false, Prompts:[]models.Prompt(nil), Folders:[]models.Folder(nil), Playgrounds:[]models.Playground(nil), PlaygroundID:uuid.UUID{0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}}, Forks:0x0, Likers:[]models.User(nil), PromptID:uuid.UUID{0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}, AuthorID:uuid.UUID{0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0}}, got error unsupported data type: &[]



// user.model.go
type User struct {
    ID           uuid.UUID    `json:"user_id" gorm:"type:uuid;default:gen_random_uuid();primary_key"`
    CreatedAt    time.Time    `json:"created_at" gorm:"not null;default:NOW()"`
    UpdatedAt    time.Time    `json:"-" gorm:"not null;NOW()"`
    Name         string       `json:"name" gorm:"type:varchar(255);not null"`
    Email        string       `json:"email" gorm:"uniqueIndex;not null"`
    Password     string       `json:"-" gorm:"not null"` // "-" excludes the Password field from JSON
    Role         string       `json:"user_role,omitempty" gorm:"type:varchar(255);not null"`
    Photo        string       `json:"photo,omitempty" gorm:"type:varchar(255);default:''"`
    ApiKey       string       `json:"-" gorm:"type:varchar(255);default:''"`
    Verified     bool         `json:"verified" gorm:"default:false"`
    Prompts      []Prompt     `json:"prompts" gorm:"foreignKey:UserID"`
    Folders      []Folder     `json:"folders" gorm:"foreignKey:UserID"`
    Playgrounds  []Playground `json:"playgrounds" gorm:"foreignKey:UserID"`
    PlaygroundID uuid.UUID    `json:"folder" gorm:"type:uuid"`
}



//folder.model.go
type Folder struct {
    ID        uuid.UUID `json:"folder_id" gorm:"type:uuid;default:gen_random_uuid();primary_key"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at" gorm:"not null;default:NOW()"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updated_at" gorm:"not null;NOW()"`
    Name      string    `json:"name" gorm:"varchar(255);not null"`
    AuthorID  uuid.UUID `json:"author_id" gorm:"type:uuid"`
    Prompts   []Prompt  `json:"prompts" gorm:"foreignKey:FolderID"`
}

// prompt.model.go
type Prompt struct {
    ID          uuid.UUID    `json:"folder_id" gorm:"type:uuid;default:gen_random_uuid();primary_key"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time    `json:"created_at" gorm:"not null;default:NOW()"`
    UpdatedAt   time.Time    `json:"updated_at" gorm:"not null;NOW()"`
    Title       string       `json:"prompt_title" gorm:"not null"`
    Prompt      string       `json:"prompt" gorm:"not null"`
  Tags        []string     `json:"tags"`
  AuthorID    uuid.UUID    `json:"author_id" gorm:"type:uuid"`
  FolderID    uuid.UUID    `json:"folder" gorm:"type:uuid"`
    Description string       `json:"description" gorm:"not null"`
    Playgrounds []Playground `json:"playgrounds" gorm:"foreignKey:PromptID"`
}

// playground.model.go
type Playground struct {
    ID         uuid.UUID `json:"playground_id" gorm:"type:uuid;default:gen_random_uuid();primary_key"`
    CreatedAt  time.Time `json:"created_at" gorm:"not null;default:NOW()"`
    UpdatedAt  time.Time `json:"update_at" gorm:"not null;NOW()"`
    Name       string    `json:"name" gorm:"varchar(255);not null"`
    Template   string    `json:"prompt_template" gorm:"not null"`
    Temprature uint      `json:"temprature" gorm:"default:3"`
    AiModel    string    `json:"ai_model" gorm:"default:'gpt-3.5-turbo'"`
    TopPValue  uint      `json:"top_p_value" gorm:"default:0"`
    Likes      uint32    `json:"likes" gorm:"default:0"`
  Author     User      `json:"author" gorm:"references:AuthorID"`
    Forks      uint32    `json:"forks_count" gorm:"default:0"`
  Likers     []User    `json:"likers" gorm:"foreignKey:PlaygroundID"`
  PromptID   uuid.UUID `json:"prompt_id"`
  AuthorID   uuid.UUID `json:"author_id"`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Fix Found ( []string is not a supported type in GORM)

So after doing a bit of digging,I found out that GORM does not support `[]string` . This mean you cannot use it directly in the GORM model.

**Funny Enough** that was the cause of all the error I was receiving (not totally) some of them were from wrongly adding foreign keys.

After doing making a change to `[]string` for the Tags field in Prompt model most of the type error dissapeared and I was able to fix the foreignKey errors.

#### Here's how the final models look like with the fix

```golang
type MultiString []string

// User Model
type User struct {
    ID           uuid.UUID `json:"user_id" gorm:"type:uuid;default:gen_random_uuid();primary_key"`
    CreatedAt    time.Time `json:"created_at" gorm:"not null;default:NOW()"`
    UpdatedAt    time.Time `json:"-" gorm:"not null;NOW()"`
    Name         string    `json:"name" gorm:"type:varchar(255);not null"`
    Email        string    `json:"email" gorm:"uniqueIndex;not null"`
    Password     string    `json:"-" gorm:"not null"` // "-" excludes the Password field from JSON
    Role         string    `json:"user_role,omitempty" gorm:"type:varchar(255);not null"`
    Photo        string    `json:"photo,omitempty" gorm:"type:varchar(255);default:''"`
    ApiKey       string    `json:"-" gorm:"type:varchar(255);default:''"`
    Verified     bool      `json:"verified" gorm:"default:false"`
    PlaygroundID uuid.UUID `json:"folder" gorm:"type:uuid"`
    Folders      []Folder  `gorm:"foreignKey:AuthorID"`
}

type Prompt struct {
    ID          uuid.UUID    `json:"folder_id" gorm:"type:uuid;default:gen_random_uuid();primary_key"`
    CreatedAt   time.Time    `json:"created_at" gorm:"not null;default:NOW()"`
    UpdatedAt   time.Time    `json:"updated_at" gorm:"not null;NOW()"`
    Title       string       `json:"prompt_title" gorm:"not null"`
    Prompt      string       `json:"prompt" gorm:"not null"`
    Tags        MultiString  `json:"tags" gorm:"type:text"`
    AuthorID    uuid.UUID    `json:"author_id" gorm:"type:uuid"`
    FolderID    uuid.UUID    `json:"folder" gorm:"type:uuid"`
    Description string       `json:"description" gorm:"not null"`
    Playgrounds []Playground `json:"playgrounds" gorm:"foreignKey:PromptID"`
}

type Playground struct {
    ID         uuid.UUID `json:"playground_id" gorm:"type:uuid;default:gen_random_uuid();primary_key"`
    CreatedAt  time.Time `json:"created_at" gorm:"not null;default:NOW()"`
    UpdatedAt  time.Time `json:"update_at" gorm:"not null;NOW()"`
    Name       string    `json:"name" gorm:"varchar(255);not null"`
    Template   string    `json:"prompt_template" gorm:"not null"`
    Temprature uint      `json:"temprature" gorm:"default:3"`
    AiModel    string    `json:"ai_model" gorm:"default:'gpt-3.5-turbo'"`
    TopPValue  uint      `json:"top_p_value" gorm:"default:0"`
    Likes      uint32    `json:"likes" gorm:"default:0"`
    Forks      uint32    `json:"forks_count" gorm:"default:0"`
    Author     User      `json:"author" gorm:"foreignKey:AuthorID"`
    Likers     []User    `json:"likers" gorm:"foreignKey:PlaygroundID"`
    PromptID   uuid.UUID `json:"prompt_id"`
    AuthorID   uuid.UUID `json:"author_id"`
}

type Folder struct {
    ID        uuid.UUID `json:"folder_id" gorm:"type:uuid;default:gen_random_uuid();primary_key"`
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at" gorm:"not null;default:NOW()"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time `json:"updated_at" gorm:"not null;NOW()"`
    Name      string    `json:"name" gorm:"varchar(255);not null"`
    AuthorID  uuid.UUID `json:"author_id" gorm:"type:uuid"`
    Prompts   []Prompt  `json:"prompts"`
}
```

If you noticed there is a new type defined `type MultiString []string` this is used in the Tags field => Prompt model `Tags  MultiString ...`

This was the originator of `got error unsupported data type: &[]` Error.

Sorry if I asked the question too soon, It was a blocker for quite sometime.

#### References

- [Found this post suggesting a package you can use for string arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70540637/got-error-unsupported-data-type-this-is-gorm-model-golang-jwt)
- [StringArray not supported in GORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64035165/unsupported-data-type-error-on-gorm-field-where-custom-valuer-returns-nil)